# How to save a variable to a local a desktop location

Tags: python, file, jupyter-notebook

I need to save the message subject from emails as a simple txt file on my desktop.
In the below example subject1 defines the message subject.
I have tried subject1.SaveAsFile(location) but that did not work. Since I am using Jupyter notebook, its saving locally but I need to save it on my desktop.

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
import os
import email
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import file_operations


outlook = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
message = inbox.Items

for message in inbox.Items:
    if message.UnRead == True:
       subject1 = message.Subject
```

Comment: Nothing here seems to be using Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a file to do so. Make sure `subject1` is a string, or cast it to a string with `str()`.

```py
with open('C:\\Users\\ShaneN\\Desktop\\testing\\filename.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(subject1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I save that to my desktop? I am struggling to figure out how and where I put my local desktop directory. Currently it saves it to jupyter notebook..

Comment: You can specify the path before the filename. However you should have specify in your question that it was on Jupiter Notebook, having no experience with it, I can't make sure that saving a file to a local path is possible.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the input. Sorry I dint mention I was using this in Jupyter before hand. file.write('C:\\Users\\ShaneN\\Desktop\\testing\\'+ subject1) I tried this but still not working. Thanks again Titouan.

Comment: I edited my answer with the path you provided.

Comment: Saving to a file with Jupyter Notebook doesn't work with this method.